# form tag is replaced by p tag in ckeditor on safari mac

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm running CKeditor 3 and have noticed that when I paste a form field in to source and hit save. If I then reload the page and open up the editor, the form tags have been replaced by a p tag.

How can I fix this without upgrading to ckeditor4?

Comment: Form *field* (`<input>`) or form *tag* (`<form>`)?  Are you doing any sort of server-side filtering?  (You should be.)

Comment: <form> tags, not <input>, they are staying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an issue of browser, and not a CKEditor: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/8590 . As a short conclusion, here is the quote:

> If browser strips down the nested form then this means that CKEditor receives this reduced code. There is no way CKEditor can get to that code before the browser so it simply does not know about the missing form tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the DIV EDIT CONTAINER plugin, this may be your problem.

Download the Standard CKeditor package. Install. Edit a page. Go to source view. Type in a form tag, input field, and close form tag. Go out of source view, then back into source view. No problems.

Go back to the CKeditor downloader and add the DIV EDIT CONTAINER plugin. Repeat steps above. Notice how the form tag has been transmogrified into a p tag.

And that's too bad, because I like to be able to edit pages using the site-wide style sheet.